# How to implement conjugate matrix transpose function in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, transpose

I'm new into matlab and my problem is that I'm trying to implement conjugate matrix transpose function('), but I have no idea how to change sign only in imaginary number. I know it may be stupid question but thanks for any tips and advice.

I tried something like this, but I got these errors:

- error: complex matrix type invalid as index value
- error: assignment failed, or no method for ' = matrix'

  ```
  function [ result ] = transpose_matrix( a )

   [Row,Col] = size(a);
   result = zeros(Col, Row); 
   iY=1;

   for iRow=1:Row
    iX=iRow;
     for iCol=1:Col
      result(iX)=a(iY);
      iX=iX+Row;
      iY=iY+1;
     end
   end
    imag(result)=imag(result)*-1;
  end
  ```

Comment: Why are you implementing the transpose in long-hand yourself?   `b = a';` gives you the conjugate transpose.  `b = a.';` gives you non-conjugate transpose.   `b = conj(a);` gives you the complex conjugate without transposing.   Anything you implement using `for` loops as opposed to built-in operations is veeeeeeerrrrry slow in Matlab.

Comment: just for practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MATLAB is confused because the following statement tries to treat `imag` as a variable with `result` as an index since it's on the left-hand side of the assignment.

```
imag(result) = imag(result) * (-1);
```

Also, it's important to note that `imag` returns a *real number* which is the magnitude of the imaginary component. Once you modify the output of `imag`, you need to multiply by `sqrt(-1)` to get it back to an imaginary number

```
imag(a) * (-1) * 1i;
```

Now to modify only the imaginary component of `result`, you'll want to simply add this new imaginary component with the real component of `result`.

```
result = real(result) + imag(result) * (-1) * 1i;
```

Or more simply:

```
result = real(result) - imag(result) * 1i;
```

#### A Potential Alternative

If you can use the normal `transpose` function you could replace your entire function with the following:

```
result = transpose(a);
result = real(result) - imag(result) * 1i;
```